# Why i2cdetect 0 not returning address

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, i2c, openembedded

I am trying to test I2C-0 pin on SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK board can anyone suggest what is the error.

```
root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:~# i2cdetect 0
i2cdetect: WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus
Continue? [y/N] y
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I have checked device tree it is also correct.
I don't know why error is occurring.i have also checked pin configuration it is also correct,please suggest me what us wrong and how can i get solution.please give reference if you have any.

Comment: List i2c devices with `i2cdetect -l`, and to read use `i2cdetect -y -r NUM_BUS`

Comment: See on other buses, as your device may be on another I2C, and make sure the device is "connected" correctly and using resistors in the SDA and SCL.